# How to configure two instance mongodb use spring boot and spring data

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

The First instance is the embedded MongoDb, the second instance is the live MongoDb.
How do it configure use spring data and spring boot. How to switch easily these instances by properties file??

**UPDATE**

- By default application should start build-in database and store data
  into APPDIR/db directory
- It should be possible to let application know that external database
  will be used by configuring mongo.url property. In this case no need
  to start internal database. Instead of that external connection
  should be used

Paste some configuration, please.

**UPDATE**
I have:

```
<!--Embedded MongoDB-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
    <version>1.50.5</version>
</dependency>

spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost/test
spring.data.mongodb.database=test

# EMBEDDED MONGODB (EmbeddedMongoProperties)
#spring.mongodb.embedded.storage.databaseDir=c:/db
#spring.mongodb.embedded.version=3.2.2
```

if I'll specify external mongodb, then i want  embedded mongodb shouldn't to startup.

```
java.io.IOException: Could not start process: <EOF>
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.AbstractMongoProcess.onAfterProcessStart(AbstractMongoProcess.java:79) ~[de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo-1.50.5.jar!/:?]
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.runtime.AbstractProcess.<init>(AbstractProcess.java:114) [de.flapdoodle.embed.process-1.50.2.jar!/:?]
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.AbstractMongoProcess.<init>(AbstractMongoProcess.java:53) [de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo-1.50.5.jar!/:?]
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.MongodProcess.<init>(MongodProcess.java:50) [de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo-1.50.5.jar!/:?]
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.MongodExecutable.start(MongodExecutable.java:44) [de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo-1.50.5.jar!/:?]
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.MongodExecutable.start(MongodExecutable.java:34) [de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo-1.50.5.jar!/:?]
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.runtime.Executable.start(Executable.java:101) [de.flapdoodle.embed.process-1.50.2.jar!/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use Spring profiles.

Here's the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html).

> Spring Profiles provide a way to segregate parts of your application
>   configuration and make it only available in certain environments.

### UPDATE

**Note :** Everything that I will talk about below is indicated in the documentation I mentioned above... You should really take a look to this documentation. This documentation is great (no joke).

From [Appendix A. Common application properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) (Spring boot documentation)

Here's how to configuration remote MongoDB instance in `application.properties` :

```
# MONGODB (MongoProperties)
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database= # Authentication database name.
spring.data.mongodb.database=test # Database name.
spring.data.mongodb.field-naming-strategy= # Fully qualified name of the FieldNamingStrategy to use.
spring.data.mongodb.grid-fs-database= # GridFS database name.
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost # Mongo server host.
spring.data.mongodb.password= # Login password of the mongo server.
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017 # Mongo server port.
spring.data.mongodb.repositories.enabled=true # Enable Mongo repositories.
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost/test # Mongo database URI. When set, host and port are ignored.
spring.data.mongodb.username= # Login user of the mongo server.
```

And here's how to configure embedded MongoDB instance in `application.properties`:

```
# EMBEDDED MONGODB (EmbeddedMongoProperties)
spring.mongodb.embedded.features=SYNC_DELAY # Comma-separated list of features to enable.
spring.mongodb.embedded.storage.databaseDir= # Directory used for data storage.
spring.mongodb.embedded.storage.oplogSize= # Maximum size of the oplog in megabytes.
spring.mongodb.embedded.storage.replSetName= # Name of the replica set.
spring.mongodb.embedded.version=2.6.10 # Version of Mongo to use.
```

From [Change configuration depending on the environment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-change-configuration-depending-on-the-environment) (Spring boot documentation)

> To do the same thing with properties files you can use
>   `application-${profile}.properties` to specify profile-specific values.

You can define the MongoDB embedded configuration into `application-dev.properties` and the MongoDB remote configuration into `application-prod.properties`

### UPDATE II : The return

I'm assuming that you start your embedded MongoDB instance in a class like (from [documentation](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo#usage)) :

```
import de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.config.ArtifactStoreBuilder;

    ...
    MongodStarter starter = MongodStarter.getDefaultInstance();

    String bindIp = "localhost";
    int port = 12345;
    IMongodConfig mongodConfig = new MongodConfigBuilder()
        .version(Version.Main.PRODUCTION)
        .net(new Net(bindIp, port, Network.localhostIsIPv6()))
        .build();

    MongodExecutable mongodExecutable = null;
```

You can assign a spring profile to this class like (from [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)) :

```
@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
public class ProductionConfiguration {

    // ...

}
```

This way, your embedded MongoDB is started only when you choose `dev` profile.

Comment: can you paste some configuration?

Comment: I understand how to work spring profiles, i don't understand how to configure two instance mongo db uses spring data and spring boot

Comment: Thank you, it worts for me)