# Configuring flapdoodle embedded mongo with Mongodb version 4 and replica

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, embedded-database, spring-mongodb

I am currently working on a spring boot application 2.0.3.RELEASE. I want to configure Flapdoodle MongoDb with MongoDb version 4.0 and I also want to set  a single mongo instance and create replicas for it.

So far i haven't figured out the process of creating cluster and replicas using flapdoodle.

I am using

```
         MongodConfigBuilder().version(Version.Main.DEVELOPMENT)
        .replication(new Storage(null, null, 0))
        .build();
```

i have read many questions here related to this configuration but none of them is related to my problem. eg 
[How to configure two instance mongodb use spring boot and spring data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41102476/how-to-configure-two-instance-mongodb-use-spring-boot-and-spring-data)

The flapdoodle configuration has an implemetation for this but i am not sure how to access it.

https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo/blob/master/src/main/java/de/flapdoodle/embed/mongo/tests/MongosSystemForTestFactory.java

Is there any way to configure it in my test class before application starts. 
thanks

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-embedded-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

I had to start the Embedded mongo with replicaset in web Integration tests, used below code

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig {

    public static int mongodPort;
    public static String defaultHost = "localhost";
    static {
        try {
            mongodPort = Network.getFreeServerPort();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public IMongodConfig prepareMongodConfig() throws IOException {
        IMongoCmdOptions cmdOptions = new MongoCmdOptionsBuilder()
                .useNoPrealloc(false)
                .useSmallFiles(false)
                .master(false)
                .verbose(false)
                .useNoJournal(false)
                .syncDelay(0)
                .build();

        IMongodConfig mongoConfigConfig = new MongodConfigBuilder()
                .version(Version.Main.PRODUCTION)
                .net(new Net(mongodPort, Network.localhostIsIPv6()))
                .replication(new Storage(null, "testRepSet", 5000))
                .configServer(false)
                .cmdOptions(cmdOptions)
                .build();
        return mongoConfigConfig;
    }

}
```

and before calling my controller I enabled the DB with replica set using below code

```
 Public class ITtest {
    public  void  setSystemProperty() {
            System.setProperty("spring.data.mongodb.port", String.valueOf(MongoConfig.mongodPort));
            System.setProperty("spring.data.mongodb.host", MongoConfig.defaultHost);
        }

        public static boolean isReplicaSetRun = false;

        public static void setupMongoReplica() {
            if (! isReplicaSetRun) {
                System.out.println("Starting db on port: " +MongoConfig.mongodPort);
                MongoClient client = new MongoClient(MongoConfig.defaultHost, MongoConfig.mongodPort);
                client.getDatabase("admin").runCommand(new Document("replSetInitiate", new Document()));
                client.close();
                isReplicaSetRun = true;
            }
        }

        @Test
        @Order(1)
        public void testParallel() {
            setSystemProperty();
            setupMongoReplica();
            // call web controller
      }
   }
```

If want to run application, then enabling of replicaset can be done in implementation of ApplicationListener