# Unable to connect to MongoDB using Embeded MongoDB using replicaSet for Junit test cases

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, flapdoodle-embed-mongo

I am facing the following problem while connecting to embeded MongoDB with replicaSet for executing Junit test cases. I am getting the following exception.

```
[mongod output] 2021-03-06T23:28:13.202+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.

[mongod output] 2021-03-06T23:28:13.202+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server. 

[mongod output] 2021-03-06T23:28:13.202+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP 

[mongod output] 2021-03-06T23:28:13.202+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to

[mongod output] 2021-03-06T23:28:13.202+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the

[mongod output] 2021-03-06T23:28:13.202+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.

[mongod output] 2021-03-06T23:28:13.202+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 

[mongod output] 2021-03-06T23:28:13.206+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] createCollection: local.startup_log with generated UUID: 05d4a8b0-4709-4a0d-91fa-0de499c942a0

[mongod output] 2021-03-06T23:28:13.856+0530 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory 'C:/Users/mishrd5/AppData/Local/Temp/embedmongo-db-9c4148c7-97f4-498d-bf55-a03c88a38830/diagnostic.data'

[mongod output] 2021-03-06T23:28:13.857+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] createCollection: local.replset.oplogTruncateAfterPoint with generated UUID: 3fd3b9bc-3f44-4975-ba81-8b995268f49d

[mongod output] 2021-03-06T23:28:13.879+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] createCollection: local.replset.minvalid with generated UUID: a1e095da-9f04-4cda-bd3c-cda0297f4453

[mongod output] 2021-03-06T23:28:13.910+0530 I REPL     [initandlisten] Did not find local voted for document at startup.

[mongod output] 2021-03-06T23:28:13.910+0530 I REPL     [initandlisten] Did not find local Rollback ID document at startup. Creating one.

[mongod output] 2021-03-06T23:28:13.910+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] createCollection: local.system.rollback.id with generated UUID: c82cb441-efd9-4605-abc5-c2a18bbb06c1

[mongod output] 2021-03-06T23:28:13.938+0530 I REPL     [initandlisten] Initialized the rollback ID to 1

[mongod output] 2021-03-06T23:28:13.938+0530 I REPL     [initandlisten] Did not find local replica set configuration document at startup;  NoMatchingDocument: Did not find replica set configuration document in local.system.replset

[mongod output] 2021-03-06T23:28:13.939+0530 I CONTROL  [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] Sessions collection is not set up; waiting until next sessions refresh interval: Replication has not yet been configured

[mongod output] 2021-03-06T23:28:13.939+0530 I CONTROL  [LogicalSessionCacheReap] Sessions collection is not set up; waiting until next sessions reap interval: Replication has not yet been configured

[mongod output] 2021-03-06T23:28:13.939+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27023

[mongod output] 2021-03-06 23:28:13.939  INFO 18616 --- [           main] d.f.embed.mongo.MongodExecutable         : start de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.config.MongodConfigBuilder$ImmutableMongodConfig@6870c3c2
2021-03-06 23:28:14.023  INFO 18616 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[host:27021], mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=REPLICA_SET, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', requiredReplicaSetName='rs0'}
2021-03-06 23:28:14.024  INFO 18616 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server host:27021 to client view of cluster
--------------------------------------
MongoClient : com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientImpl@53f0d09c
--------------------------------------
2021-03-06 23:28:14.092  INFO 18616 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : No server chosen by com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@5eabff6b from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=REPLICA_SET, connectionMode=MULTIPLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=host:27021, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
2021-03-06 23:28:28.297  INFO 18616 --- [ll'}-host:27021] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server host:27021

com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: host
    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:211) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:75) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:127) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_261]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: host
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1324) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1277) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:203) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

I provide below my code.

```
@Profile("test")
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@TestConfiguration
public class TestMongoDBConfig implements InitializingBean, DisposableBean {

    /** The executable. */
    private MongodExecutable executable;
    
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
    
    private MongodProcess node1Mongod;
    private MongodProcess node2Mongod;
    private MongodExecutable node1MongodExe;
    private MongodExecutable node2MongodExe;
    private int node1Port = 27021;
  private int node2Port = 27023;    
    private static final String CONNECTION_STRING = "mongodb://%s:%d";
    private int port = 27021;

    
    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {

//      IFeatureAwareVersion version = de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.distribution.Versions
//              .withFeatures(new GenericVersion("4.0.0"), Version.Main.PRODUCTION.getFeatures());
//      IMongoCmdOptions cmdOptions = new MongoCmdOptionsBuilder().useNoPrealloc(false).useSmallFiles(false)
//              .master(false).verbose(false).useNoJournal(false).syncDelay(0).build();
//      port = Network.getFreeServerPort();
//      System.out.println("-------------------------");
//      System.out.println("Test Mongo PORT : "+port);
//      System.out.println("-------------------------");
//      IMongodConfig mongodConfig = new MongodConfigBuilder().version(version)
//              .net(new Net(port, Network.localhostIsIPv6()))
////                .replication(new Storage(null, "testRepSet", 5000))
//              .replication(new Storage(null, "rs0", 5000))
//            .configServer(true)
////            .withLaunchArgument("--replSet", "rs0")
////                .configServer(false)
//              .cmdOptions(cmdOptions).build();
//      MongodStarter starter = MongodStarter.getDefaultInstance();
//      executable = starter.prepare(mongodConfig);
//      executable.start();
        
        //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        MongodStarter runtime = MongodStarter.getDefaultInstance();
        
        
        
        node1MongodExe = runtime.prepare(new MongodConfigBuilder().version(Version.Main.V4_0)
                  .withLaunchArgument("--replSet", "rs0")
                  .cmdOptions(new MongoCmdOptionsBuilder().useNoJournal(false).build())
                  .net(new Net(node1Port, Network.localhostIsIPv6())).build());
          node1Mongod = node1MongodExe.start();

          node2MongodExe = runtime.prepare(new MongodConfigBuilder().version(Version.Main.V4_0)
                  .withLaunchArgument("--replSet", "rs0")
                  .cmdOptions(new MongoCmdOptionsBuilder().useNoJournal(false).build())
                  .net(new Net(node2Port, Network.localhostIsIPv6())).build());
          node2Mongod = node2MongodExe.start();
        
    }

    /**
     * Mongo client.
     *
     * @return the mongo client
     */
//  @Primary
    @Bean(name = "test1")
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(cs);
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("MongoClient : "+mongoClient);
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
        
        
        MongoDatabase adminDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("admin");

          Document config = new Document("_id", "rs0");
          BasicDBList members = new BasicDBList();
          members.add(new Document("_id", 0)
                  .append("host", "localhost:" + node1Port));
          members.add(new Document("_id", 1)
                  .append("host", "localhost:" + node2Port));
          config.put("members", members);

          adminDatabase.runCommand(new Document("replSetInitiate", config));

        return mongoClient;
    }


    @Override
    public void destroy() throws Exception {
        executable.stop();
    }
}
```

Please ignore the commented code. I have also refered the follwoing links, but no success.

https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo/issues/257

[Test @Transactional with Flapdoodle Embedded MongoDB in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61885466/test-transactional-with-flapdoodle-embedded-mongodb-in-spring-boot)

[Configuring flapdoodle embedded mongo with Mongodb version 4 and replica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51499482/configuring-flapdoodle-embedded-mongo-with-mongodb-version-4-and-replica)

Please help me.

Comment: this class which you posted is not working. can you post some example somewhere on github? btw even developer of embedded mongo is suggesting to not use replica in unit tests ;) If you really need replica what about using [this](https://github.com/silaev/mongodb-replica-set/)?

Comment: Why is server log mixed with your application output? Connect with mongo shell, then troubleshoot your application.

Comment: How can I connect to embeded MongoDB shell?